# How/where to store the current users login name?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# winforms application deployed to a terminal server with AD. I would like that when the user launches the application, the user name is pre-filled, so they don't have to type it each time. What's the best way to store and then retrieve that value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the name of the user currently running the application then use `Environment.UserName`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Environment.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) to get the username of the user currently logged in to Windows.

However, `Environment.UserName` is read-only, so you won't be able to set it.